# How to play audio file in react-native? Primarily in android

Tags: javascript, android, audio, react-native

I am trying really hard to play an audio file from my react-native app.
Currenty I am trying to use this package:

[react-native-sound](https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound)

But can not get it to work properly, I get this error: 
Cannot read property IsAndroid of undefined, which it tries to do in sound.js line 4 of the react-native-sound package:

`var RNSound = require('react-native').NativeModules.RNSound;
 var IsAndroid = RNSound.IsAndroid;`

Probably this means that the RNSound object is not registered correctly.

Anyways, it seems the package is not being maintained anymore with 33 issues and 8 pull request, and last commit was 4 months ago.

So, how do you guys add audio to your projects? I am using React Native 0.37 btw.

Comment: This may help https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound/issues/36

Comment: Thanks, that thread helped alot! I will write an answer to my own question, based on that thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so based on [Nirav Ranpara's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1686001/nirav-ranpara)
comment and the link he provided:
https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound/issues/36

These are the stepsto take to make it work in android using React Native 0.37 

1. Edit android/settings.gradle to declare the project directory:

```
include ':RNSound', ':app'
project(':RNSound').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-sound/android')
```

2. Edit android/app/build.gradle to declare the project dependency:

```
   dependencies {
     ...
     compile project(':RNSound')
   }
```

3. Edit android/app/src/main/java/.../MainApplication.java to register the native module:

NOTE: **MainApplication.java** not  MainActivity.java

```
...
import com.zmxv.RNSound.RNSoundPackage;
...

...
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
      new MainReactPackage(), // don't forget your comma
      new RNSoundPackage() // insert this line
  );
}
...
```

4. Import in your application like this:

```
import { default as Sound } from 'react-native-sound';
```

NOTE **don't do this**:

```
// wrong
var Sound = require('react-native-sound');

// also wrong
import {Sound} from 'react-native-sound';
```

NOTE: Step 1 and 2 are same as the documentation, while 3 and 4 differ.